# Best-Fit Allocation: What Happens When All Blocks Are the Same Size?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

[image]

As shown in the image, each block is 2 Kbytes in size.

If I were asked to allocate 1 Kbyte of memory, which block would the Best-Fit algorithm allocate? Given that all blocks are the same size, which one should be chosen, considering all are equally suitable for Best-Fit?

I expected the Best-Fit algorithm to allocate 1 Kbyte of memory in Block 2. However, that was not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

When all blocks are the same there is no built-in preference to select a particular block for Best Fit Algorithm. Since all empty blocks can accommodate the requested 1 Kbyte memory, the selection can depend on other implementation ideas or logic.

Comment: No, unfortunately, that's all the information we have regarding the question. There are no additional implementation ideas or logic provided.